# To handle the increment and decrement of a value in an expression and display the corresponding indicator SSRS reporting service

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table table of values displayed in SSRS . 
The table has fields `metricID , currentmonth , preciousMonth`

Questions :-
1. I have to compare 2 values like current month and previous month

```
Fields.PreviousMonth.Value < Fields.CurrentMonth.Value
```

1. THEn Check if the metric id is metricID is 7 then increase in currentmonth should be displayed as up arrow with red colour else it should be downarrow with green colour.
2. For all other Metric ID's it should be "upp arrow with green colour" else "down arrow with red colour"

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will need to set up custom indicators and set an appropriate expression to set the indicator.

I have some simple data:

[image]

And a simple report with an indicator per row:

[image]

The indicator is set up as:

[image]

Where the expression is:

```
=Switch(Fields!MetricID.Value = 7 and Fields!CurrentMonth.Value - Fields!PreviousMonth.Value > 0, 1
    , Fields!MetricID.Value = 7, 2
    , Fields!MetricID.Value <> 7 and Fields!CurrentMonth.Value - Fields!PreviousMonth.Value > 0, 3
    , true, 4)
```

So what I'm doing is assigning each row a specified state based on your business rules, and I've set appropriate icons for each of those states.

Report is working as required:

[image]

You could move the expression above into a calculated field in the Dataset if you needed to use it in multiple places in the report.

Comment: Hi thanks very much. This is perfect. Do you know how do i handle NULL. I d'nt want to put an indicator for null.. Why i am worried is I am using Lookup to get the current and previous month values.. so lookup of NULL value is 0. Also i need an indicator if the current and previous month values are equal as yellow and horizontal arrow.

Comment: Thanks i got he solution. I used IsNothing and checked for null